# Batch to update IP address of a string in a text file

Tags: batch-file

Please assist me on the below script as I need to update machine IP address in a config file followed by a particular string. Script as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET CONFFILE="C:\Test\agent.properties"

set ip_address_string="IP Address"

for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %%I in (
    'netsh interface ip show config "Ethernet" | findstr "IP Address:"'
) do (
    @ECHO tw.rpc.interfaceAddr=%%I>>%CONFFILE%
)

goto :EOF
```

Kindly suggest for corrections as needed.

Comment: Does it error? If so, what's the error?

Comment: Why you use literal instead of defined `%ip_address_string%`? Are you sure the interface name you need is "Ethernet"? Why you select **three** tokens and save **first** token (the IP address is 5th with used delimiters list)?

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code

1. findstr by default uses RegEx mode where strings separated by a space are looked for in an OR fashion/independently. Use `/C:` argument
2. A command in a `for /f` uses a 2nd cmd.exe invocation, so chars `<|>&` have to be escaped with a caret `^`

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "CONFFILE=C:\Test\agent.properties"
set "ip_address_string=IP Address"

for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %%I in (
    'netsh interface ip show config "Ethernet"^| findstr /C:"%ip_address_string%"'
) do ECHO tw.rpc.interfaceAddr=%%I>>"%CONFFILE% "
```